# Symfony api-platform: user should retrieve his own entities

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I have this entity

```
/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FeedRepository")
*/
class Feed implements AuthoredEntityInterface
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="myFeeds")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=2083, unique=true)
 */
private $url;

// various getters and setters

}
```

using the AuthoredEntityInterface I made I can automatically set the user to the logged user.

I'd need to know how to set the collectionOperations so when I am logged in as the user with id = 1, when I call /api/feeds I will only retrieve items with user = 1. If this is possible I would like to do this with an annotation, otherwise any other method is ok.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is just for connected user, what you need is a current user extension (doctrine extension). Else, you need to create a "subresource' link.

Link to [Extension](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions/), and to [Subresource](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/).

Enjoy :) (and thank you timisorean for the review)

Comment: Thanks Florian, I approved this answer because looking at the documentation this is exactly what I was looking for (Extension). However for some reason the extension is not triggered even if I run console debug:container I can see it is correcly registered. Any idea? thanks.

Comment: Here I need more informations ... is your extension correctly registered in services.yaml? Have you a git which I can clone?

Comment: sure:
https://bitbucket.org/msechi/symfony4-api-platform-test/branch/bank-feed-entity

thank you

Comment: I saw your test (print 12345), you can't test doctrine extension by this way. What you do in these functions is not returned. It runs before sql execution. Try to force the register in services.yaml. Remove the if in addWhere and correctly set the $user. and ... good luck :)